# c# where clause, instead of for loop

Tags: c#, floating-point

In my C# Form script, I have array which contains like 2-3k elements. I need to find a specific value in that array but without applying for loop to it. Looping trough 2-3k elements will cause couple of seconds delay, and i dont want that. This is similar to Mysql database for a website.

In PHP websites i was using where clause on indexed database, so even if the table had 1 milion rows, i was able to get the only row i needed in 0.020 second. Is there something similar for C#?

Here is what i'm trying to achieve.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static float[] data = {140, 160, 170, 180, 190, 54235243,234,4213,1234,543,1234,3215,52134,1234,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999};
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var queryLowNums =
            from num in data
            where num > 140 and num < 170
            select num;
        
        // num should be 160
        
    }
}
```

This code above is invalid ofc, im just trying to give example of what im trying to do. Is there such syntax/command or whatever, anything that can help me in this situation. Looping trough 2-3k elements will take like a second maybe or 2 seconds idk. I know that if i have the index of a given element, it will load it directly without the need of for loop. But idk how to achieve that.

Comment: 2k-3k values is nothing. Why do you think it would take seconds to complete?

Comment: In the database the values are stored in a tree like data structure. You can achieve similar in c# if you sort the values and do a binary search. It really depends on your data and use case which strategy is the best.

Comment: Consider using a better structure such as a hashmap/`Dictionary`, or a sorted list with binary search, that will probably be the fastest. This has nothing to do with [tag:visual-studio], please don't spam tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 
    float[] data = { 140, 160, 170, 180, 190, 54235243, 234, 4213, 1234, 543, 1234, 3215, 52134, 1234, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };

    float queryLowNums = 0;
    var startIndex = 0;
    Parallel.For(startIndex, data.Length, (j, state) =>
   {
       if (data[j] > 140 && data[j] < 170)
       {
           queryLowNums = data[j];
           state.Break();
       }
   });
```

output

```
160
```

or if you are expecting several numbers

```
    var primeNumbers = new ConcurrentBag<float>();

    Parallel.ForEach(data, number =>
    {
       if (number > 140 && number < 170)
        {
            primeNumbers.Add(number);
        }
    });
```

using a hash table would be much faster, but in your case if you don't have it , it takes less time to find an item then to create a hash table if it is not exist. The same about sorting algorithms.

Comment: @Charles OP wants the fastest method. It is faster then for loop, but to use hash will be faster.

Comment: Ok, it works, i saw that it is used for matrixes also, that's what i am aiming for btw, thanks. I will test it and i hope it works. But is this still a loop?

Comment: This seems unnecessary for the size of the data in question.

Comment: @VictorTheBeast Loops are inevitable in some way or another. As Charlieface and others have pointed out, if you want efficient retrieval, you need to use a better data structure, like a binary search tree or heap or something like that. But honestly, 3k elements is not a huge array and should be processed in basically no time on a modern processor.

Comment: @siride I am agree with you . For 2-3k records a user  will not notice a difference between for and parallel.for. Difference will start from 100k at least. But maybe OP needs this code the future

Comment: @Serge Even if it gets bigger, it's probably best to pick a different algorithm or data structure than to go to multithreading, which brings its own host of inefficiencies.

Comment: @siride As you told  user will not see much difference, doesnt matter what algorithm is used. But it is always good to have some extra for the future or for the special ocasion.

Comment: @Serge I get that, but first let's remember YAGNI, and second, think of better ways to optimize this than parallelizing it. You have to have pretty big data sets before parallelization actually improves performance over better data structures or algorithms. I can't fathom this person being in that situation. And if they are, they should just use a proper library or DB instead of trying to implement a poor solution in C#.

Comment: @siride "a poor solution in C#" ?  Who are you to judge? You better read the post. "Looping trough 2-3k elements will take like a second maybe or 2 seconds idk." This solution must be working better if people decide to use it. Nobody knows what good for them better then people who use the application.

Comment: @Serge the OP doesn't actually know how long it'll take. They just conjecture that it'll take 2 to 3 seconds based on nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use List

```
var list = new List<float>() { 140, 160, 170, 180, 190 };
var index = list.IndexOf(160);

 var values = list.Where(x=>x > 140 && x < 190); //it`s work very fast
```

Comment: That's not the same as `where num > 140 and num < 170`

Comment: Indeed. I don't know hte value between 140 and 170. It could be 161.

Comment: Your new version with `list.Where` still loops the entire list